# How to reset values in nested while loops?

Tags: java

Not sure if my title is relevant to the problem I have but im trying to print a rectangle using a method with 2 parameters (width and height)
width works fine but I cant get height working.

I've commented out the nested while loop which I thought would solve the problem but once the width loop has completed once "i" still has max value of 17 from the original first loop. The exercises so far have been fairly simple so not sure if this is the rough way the problem was intended to be solved or if there is an easier way?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    printrectangle(17,3);
    }


public static void printrectangle(int width, int height) {
    int i = 0;
    int p = 0;

    //while (p < height) {
        while (i < width) {
            System.out.println("*");
            i++;
            }
        //p++;
        //}



}
```

}

Comment: I would highlight that prinln() outputs a carriage return / line feed after each string, and you likely don't want this. Worth investigating print() ?

Comment: just move the `int i = 0;` declaration/initialization inside the outer loop, before the second `while` (and learn about `for` loops, more appropriate for this case IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
while (p < height) {
    // print line with width i
    while (i < width) {
        // print without ln
        System.out.print("*");
        i++;
    }
    // completed a line, then reset i
    i = 0;
    // next line
    System.out.println();
    p++;
}
```

Comment: @VeryJazzy i've updated my answer, look at the print and println